# Should indentation always be minimized?

Tags: coding-style, indentation, conventions

I would like to hear your opinion regarding to whether it is good to minimize the indentation.

This is how I usually do it, to handle problems:

```
int foo_a() {
    if (!check_value(x)) {
        // error
        return false;
    }
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    return true;
}
```

On the other hand, I also saw such code:

```
int foo_b() {
    if (!check_value(x)) {
        // error
        return false;
    } else {
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        return true;
    }
}

int foo_c() {
    if (check_value(x)) {
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        return true;
    } else {
        // error
        return false;
    }
}
```

But this is probably contraproductive since the idents would become very large, if every check will create a new else-branch.

On the other hand, for decisions, e.g. vegetable or meat, I usually do it this way:

```
int foo_d(FOOD food) {
    if (food.isVegetable) {
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        return;
    } else {
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        return;
    }
    // assume here is NO shared code which is always executed for both food types.
}
```

But doing it like the way foo_a() does, it should look like this:

```
int foo_e(FOOD food) {
    if (food.isVegetable) {
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        // do stuff
        return;
    }

    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is not about intendation but about multiple return statements, error checking and (unnecessary) else clauses.

Comment: It does not necessarily need to have a return value. The question is, where I should use an "else" for a good coding-style, and where to have just an "if" with a return at its end (return with or without value).

Comment: Thats what I said, it's not about intendation (And I didn't mention return values anywhere). So - in my opinion - you should rephrase your question and the title.

Comment: i'll delete my answer, i i'm confused about what is asked :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally believe that both

```
if(flag) {
    //long computation
    return;
} else {
    //long computation
    return;
}
```

as well as

```
if(flag) {
    //long computation
    return;
}
//long computation
return;
```

are antipatterns, because they make it more difficult to reason about program flow and the possible return values. They also more likely result in errors during refactoring - or in general during later modifications, as one might overlook the first return statement.

For that reason, some coding guidelines allow only one return statement per function. In this case you will always have to use `if` and `else`:

```
int foo(int param) {
    int retval = 0;
    if (param > 0) {
        //computation
        retval = 5;
    } else {
        //computation
        retval = -1;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Personally I usually allow two **areas** where return statements are allowed:
Right at the beginning for abnormal or trivial  returns (e.g. parameter checking as in your `foo_a()` -example) and at the very end, where the regular return value is returned. Note that there can be multipe return statements in both areas, although it is uncommon for my functions, to have multiple "regular" exit points.

```
int foo2(int param1, int param2) {
    if (!precondition1(param1)) return -1;//error
    if (!precondition2(param2)) return -2;//error
    if (param1==param2) return 0; // no error, but answer can be determined trivially       

    //computation

    return local_variable; //return regular result
}
```

here the first two return statements at the beginning might also be asserts or exceptions.

If I do two different computations depending on the value of a flag or parameter (like `food.isVegetable`) I always use if-else and a single return statement after both as in the first example above.

Also, if the level of intendation becomes too high, you might want to consider writing a separate function. This is not always possible but more often, than you might think. E.g. for erro checking, you can write a wrapper around the actual function that checkes for faulty input:

```
int fooChecked(int param) {
    int retVal;
    if (param > 0 && param < 200) {
        retval = foo(param);
    } else {
        retVal = -1;            
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of style but I would choose the way with less code and less indentation.

If you keep functions short by extracting functions it should remain readable whichever you choose. e.g:

```
int foo_e(FOOD food) {
    if (food.isVegetable)
        return foo_vegetable(food);

    return foo_meat(food);
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, what do you think is more important, the code readability and size, or to avoid that accidential mistakes result in problems, in worst case security flaws? For example, if accidently the return inside the "vegetable" branch gets removed or forgotten, then the "meat" branch will be executed, which would not be the case if an "else" would have been used.

Comment: In my experience increased readability almost always leads to less chance of accidental mistakes. To be honest you should be aiming to use OOP, Polymorphism and design patterns like Strategy and Abstract Factory to minimise these kinds of ifs.